# Protractor can't run in Firefox (works fine in Chrome)

Tags: selenium, protractor

While trying to run my very simple test suite that I've finally started building out -- I'm receiving this amongst the error log:

```
WebDriverError: Firefox option was set, but is not a FirefoxOption: {}
```

I'm running the following versions:

- Node v7.5.0
- Protractor v5.1.1
- Selenium Webdriver v3.0.1
- Firefox v45.0.1 and now v51.0.1

Full error dump:

```
[00:44:20] I/testLogger - [firefox #11] PID: 77949
[firefox #11] Specs: /Users/meetbryce/Dropbox (Personal)/Code/Projects/HelloMetrics/utm-link-manager/protractor/auth/login.spec.js
[firefox #11] 
[firefox #11] (node:77949) DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
[firefox #11] [00:44:20] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[firefox #11] 
[firefox #11] /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:505
[firefox #11]         throw new ctor(message);
[firefox #11]               ^
[firefox #11] WebDriverError: Firefox option was set, but is not a FirefoxOption: {}
[firefox #11] Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'
[firefox #11] System info: host: 'bryceyork.local', ip: '10.40.66.60', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.1', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
[firefox #11] Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
[firefox #11]     at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:505:15)
[firefox #11]     at parseHttpResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
[firefox #11]     at doSend.then.response (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:440:13)
[firefox #11]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
[firefox #11] From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
[firefox #11]     at Function.createSession (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:777:24)
[firefox #11]     at Function.createSession (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox/index.js:640:55)
[firefox #11]     at createDriver (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:167:33)
[firefox #11]     at Builder.build (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:629:16)
[firefox #11]     at Hosted.getNewDriver (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:52:33)
[firefox #11]     at Runner.createBrowser (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:194:43)
[firefox #11]     at q.then.then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:338:29)
[firefox #11]     at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
[firefox #11]     at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
[firefox #11]     at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)

[00:44:20] I/testLogger - 

[00:44:20] E/launcher - Runner process exited unexpectedly with error code: 1
[00:44:20] I/launcher - 1 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
..[00:44:27] I/testLogger - 
------------------------------------

[00:44:27] I/testLogger - [chrome #01] PID: 77948
[chrome #01] Specs: /Users/meetbryce/Dropbox (Personal)/Code/Projects/HelloMetrics/utm-link-manager/protractor/auth/login.spec.js
[chrome #01] 
[chrome #01] (node:77948) DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
[chrome #01] [00:44:20] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[chrome #01] Started
[chrome #01] log: []
[chrome #01] log: []
[chrome #01] 
[chrome #01] 
[chrome #01] 
[chrome #01] 2 specs, 0 failures
[chrome #01] Finished in 5.816 seconds
[chrome #01] 

[00:44:27] I/testLogger - 

[00:44:27] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[00:44:27] I/launcher - firefox #11 failed with exit code: 1
[00:44:27] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed
[00:44:27] I/launcher - overall: 1 process(es) failed to complete
[00:44:27] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100

Process finished with exit code 100
```

Here's my protractor config in case that's important:

```
exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine',
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['**/*.spec.js'],
    multiCapabilities: [
        {
            'browserName': 'chrome',
            'loggingPrefs': {
                'driver': 'WARNING',
                'server': 'WARNING',
                'browser': 'SEVERE'
            }
        },
        {
            'browserName': 'firefox'
        }
    ]
};
```

Comment: Try this: 
`capabilities: { browserName: 'firefox', marionette: false }`

Comment: @FCin seems to have done something. getting `You may not use a custom command executor with the legacy FirefoxDriver` as an error now though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the exact same problem.
Launched today a "webdriver-manager update"
And then everything worked fine

EDIT:
[update command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zjBj.png)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry cant comment can only answer - someone in the past seems to have had a similar issue:
https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/3115

I can also reproduce this - And I've also recently done a webdriver-manager update

Answer (score 0):

For any Firefox versions below v48 you'll need to run with the legacy FirefoxDriver. Setting `marionette: false` as @FCin [suggested in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42220507/protractor-cant-run-in-firefox-works-fine-in-chrome#comment71610832_42220507) will tell selenium-webdriver to use the legacy FirefoxDriver, but it will later fail [with the error you described](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42220507/protractor-cant-run-in-firefox-works-fine-in-chrome#comment71635558_42220507) because it can't run using the Standalone Selenium Server. To get it to work you'll also need to remove the `seleniumAddress` from your config and replace it with [`directConnect: true`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/server-setup.md#connecting-directly-to-browser-drivers) like so:

```
exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine',
    directConnect: true,
    specs: ['**/*.spec.js'],
    multiCapabilities: [
        {
            'browserName': 'chrome',
            'loggingPrefs': {
                'driver': 'WARNING',
                'server': 'WARNING',
                'browser': 'SEVERE'
            }
        },
        {
            'browserName': 'firefox'
        }
    ]
};
```

Unfortunately, a bug was introduced in Protractor v5.1.0 that broke the integration with the legacy FirefoxDriver. You'll need to downgrade it to v5.0.0 if you want to run on Firefox v45.0.1

Answer (score -2):

add the following in your conf file

```
capabilities: {browserName: 'firefox'}
```